# how to access server using cmd( \\Server\Volume\File)

Tags: cmd

I need to get folder names in my server, as you know when you start cmd.exe it has default path name like "C:\Documents and ....". I can get folder names which are in my "C:/" by typing `dir *.* /b /o:n > index.txt`.

so I have this;
`C:\Documents and Settings\Name>dir *.* /b /o:n > index.txt`

I need this if there is a way;
`\\Server\Volume\File>dir *.* /b /o:n > index.txt`

sorry for my broken english, any help wellcome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use:

```
pushd \\Server\Volume
dir
popd
```

Answer (score 4):

You could map the drive and then browse that directory:

```
net use Z: \\Server\Volume
cd /d Z:\
dir
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: pushd assigns an available drive letter automatically, see my answer